# Planning to setup an encrypted data drive only. Not OS or swap

Tags: server, encryption, luks

Planning to setup an encrypted data drive only. Not OS or swap. This is on a server and my concern is that the data at rest must be encrypted.

The goal is to have a drive or partition, or even a shared folder, where files are dropped off but that data on drive is encrypted. Currently I have an sftp server where users can drop off files that are encrypted by them using PGP, but I want to make sure if they accidentally send a file that is not encrypted and then at rest on the server, that it is safe if hacked. Need to move existing and accept new files to an encrypted state on the drive. Open to easiest solution since the default state of the data received will be pre-encrypted with PGP.

Is LUKS the best option?
Can my server reboot without having to enter a password?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts about your scenario.

In terms of robustness and implementation of the encryption LUKS is the best choice. However, you will never be completely safe against attackers unless the server is switched off, since as long as it is running and the partition is decrypted, an attacker gaining access to your server can access the data. There is really no other way of preventing that than to encrypt each file before storing it on the server, as you already do.

I do not know of a way to reboot your server without having to enter a password either, since you don't want to store a keyfile on an unencrypted system partition. Even with full-disk encryption, you will need to provide a password, keyfile or PGP key on boot somehow. But maybe someone else is more knowledgeable about that.

For more information about the various options I recommend the always excellent [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_a_non-root_file_system#Automated_unlocking_and_mounting)

From what you're describing, I think your best solution would be using an open-source cloud solution such as [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) (don't worry, contrary to the site's appearance you can freely self-host it on your own server). That would encrypt the data in transit and at rest, storing the data in its own repository encrypted with the users keys/passwords. An attacker gaining access to your server does not automatically have access to the stored data unless they know a user or admin key. The server could also reboot on its own since it's not a whole partition that needs to be unlocked, but rather a container used by the application. The trade-off is that you need to trust Nextcloud.